# Parsing a JSON file in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON document (which is in a seperate file) using query.

The document is in a directory.
I'm running this only my local machine using Apache2

The JQuery file's path is (from project root): `/js/calc/costs.js`
The JSON file's path is (from project root): `/json/baseCosts.json`

Relevant code:

```
var jsonFile = '../../json/baseCosts.json';

calculate(1,0,jsonFile);

function calculate(typeVal, levelVal, jsonFile) {
        var jsonObject = $.getJSON(jsonFile);
        console.log(jsonObject);
}
```

(I've omitted unnecessary code)

That is where the code fails. After examining the logs, it appears that there is a 404 error when the jsonObject retrieval is attempted.

Anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Because your path is wrong. Try an absolute link.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var jsonFile = '/json/baseCosts.json';

calculate(1,0,jsonFile);

function calculate(typeVal, levelVal, jsonFile) {
        var jsonObject = $.getJSON(jsonFile);
        console.log(jsonObject);
}
```

Notice the path?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just request /json/baseCosts.json directly?

Answer (score 0):

The path is relative to where the page is loaded from, not where the Javascript is loaded from.

If the page is in the same folder as the `json` folder, then the path is:

```
var jsonFile = 'json/baseCosts.json';
```

The `getJSON` method only returns the XHR object used to send the request, use the callback function that you can specify in the call to handle the response:

```
function calculate(typeVal, levelVal, jsonFile) {
  $.getJSON(jsonFile, function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getJSON has a callback function

```
function calculate(typeVal, levelVal, jsonFile) {
    $.getJSON(jsonFile, function(jsonObject) {
        console.log(jsonObject);
    });
}
```